# ibuffer - Cursor on buffer which it was called from

Tags: ibuffer

Ibuffer is great, I  use it with filter groups which work great. I call Ibuffer using by a keypress, the problem is that the cursor is always on the first buffer in the first category. What I need is that it is on the buffername which it was called from. I mean if I'm in notes.org and call ibuffer the cursor should be on notes.org.

Any variables that can help me out there? I couldn't find any. I assume elisp is needed to solve it but I have no ability to code.

Comment: The first buffer in `*Ibuffer*` should be the buffer from which you invoked `ibuffer`. Is this not the case for you?

Comment: Yeah, by default point should be on the first buffer in the list which should be the one you started from.  Have you configured `ibuffer-filter-groups` or something similar?  I wonder if that's changed the behaviour...

Comment: Yes, I configured `setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ibuffer will sort by recency and start at the first line, which would be the buffer you just came from. Customizing ibuffer -- for example, changing the default sort order -- may result in different behavior.

You can define an ibuffer hook to always jump to the most recent buffer with something like this:

```
(defun ibuffer-jump-to-last-buffer ()
  (ibuffer-jump-to-buffer (buffer-name (cadr (buffer-list)))))

(add-hook 'ibuffer-hook #'ibuffer-jump-to-last-buffer)
```

You might also be interested in customizing `ibuffer-always-show-last-buffer`, which ensures that the most recent buffer is displayed in the ibuffer list even if some other filter would have excluded it.

Comment: Your elisp function works like hell, it's now a permanent part of my configuration.org. Thank you so much. I'll have a look at that variable too, never had such a problem though - yet.